# Math.Round(decimal) Problem

Tags: math, c#-3.0

Ok this is new, Math.Round(1.5) returns 2, i need 1.

How to handle this?

[EDITED] I know its the elementary default way, i need the opposite.

Wrong typing meaning.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Actually that answer is correct. It is the way I learned to round in elementary school.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Math.Floor() or Math.Ceiling()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xaz41263%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) ...?

Answer (score 4):

You can adjust the result.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef48waz8.aspx